What is a "correct logic" re the logical monism/pluralism/nihilism debate?
Logical monism is often described in papers as the position that there is one "correct" logic (or consequence relationship; I have seen "genuine logic" and "true logic" in papers too). Pluralism gets described as the position that there are "multiple correct logics," and nihilism as the idea that there are "no correct logics."
Broadly speaking, what is meant by the term "correct logic" here?
I was under the impression that in logic truth was just satisfaction, and that logicians had no notion of truth outside reference to specific formal systems. But then how can one judge "correctness" or "truth" between different logics?

Indeed you cannot evaluate the satisfiability of one logic calculus in terms of another different system, instead usually one clings to metalogical consistency or soundness to evaluate their absolute individual correctness as 'truth' satisfied in the meta... Incidentally in this sense it could be said that math precedes (comes before) mere logic...
